# Calling JS Parameter in HTML?

Tags: javascript

External JS Code is like so:

```
function open(sesame)  
{//my javascript function//}

open('the door');
```

My HTML is like so:

```
<a href="javascript:open()"><p>The click</p></a>
```

I want my HTML to print out the 'the door' parameter, but it doesn't seem to acknowledge it. How would I get my HTML to recognize and print out 'the door' on my open() request?

Comment: `javascript:open('the door')`?  Doesn't that work?

Comment: Note: I wouldn't name a function `open`, it could clash with `window.open`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are calling your function twice.

Once immediately after defining it (with an argument) where you pay no attention to the return value.

Then again using the `javascript:` URI scheme (which would cause the current document to be replaced with whatever the function returned), but without passing any arguments.

If you want to use the argument when you click the link, then you need to use it there.

You also need to return something from your function. You failed to tell us what you are doing inside it, so you might have further problems concealed within.

```
<script>
  function open(sesame) {
    return sesame;
  }
</script>
<a href="javascript:open('the door')">Clicky</a>
```

Such: http://jsbin.com/UKIgixe/1/edit

Note, however, that the use of the `javascript:` URI scheme is horrible. You should 
follow the principles of [Progressive Enhancement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Progressive_enhancement) and [Unobtrusive JavaScript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript).

Answer (score -1):

```
<a  href="#" onclick="open('the door');">The Click</a>
```